# Read String Line by Line Assembly X86 64

Tags: assembly, comparison, line

I am recreating the diff function in UNIX for an assignment. I only have to check wether a line has been changed, not added or deleted. We are allowed to insert the strings by creating those in the code itself (not reading from a .txt file or from the terminal). I am stuck at reading the line that has been changed. What I have achieved is to determine which character has been changed. How can I make my program compare strings line by line?

My code for now:

```
.text
    Waar: .asciz "Gelijk \n"
    NWaar: .asciz "Niet gelijk %d\n"
    String1:    .asciz "abcd\nefgh"
    String2:    .asciz "abcd\neagh"

.global main

    main:


        movq    $String1, %rsi
        movq    $String2, %rdi
        movq    $8, %rcx
        movq    $1, %r8
        cld
        loop:
            cmpsb
            jne     False
            incq    %r8
            jmp loop
        end:

        movq    $0, %rax
        movq    $Waar, %rdi
        call    printf
        call    exit

    False:
        movq    $NWaar, %rdi
        movq    %r8, %rsi
        movq    $0, %rax
        call    printf
        call    exit

    Exit:
        movq    $0, %rdi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first write your code in a higher-level language, then translate to assembly. You might start with something like:

```
int lines_are_equal(char const *a, char const *b)
{
  while (*a&&*b)               //until zero-terminated...
    {
      if (*a != *b)            //or the two strings differ...
        {
          return 0;            //return false if different
        }
      if (*a == '\n')          //if newline is encountered
        {
          break;               //break to return true
        }
      a++;                     //loop until end of string or
      b++;                     //end of line
    }
 return 1;                     //if end of string or end of line is encountered
                               //before strings differ, return true.
}
```

You probably also need a function that skips to the beginning of the next line, to invoke `lines_are_equal()` on the next line...